# How to count the number of groups returned by a group by?

Tags: mysql, count, group-by

```
select count(*) as count from table
group by foreign_id order by count
```

This returns a number of matches for each foreign id.  However what im looking for is to summarise the results.

So the result would be:

```
10 results grouping 1 elements
5  results grouping 2 elements
7  results grouping 7 elements
```

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "_n_ results grouping _n_ elements" What is to be grouped?

Comment: I don't quite get this `5 results grouping 2 elements`. What do the `5` and `2` represent there?

Comment: Its quite hard to explain.  Currently if its matched the foreign key once it will say 1 match then it will move onto the next and say 1 match then two matches for another.  What im looking to do is determine how many times its found 1 match.  Or how many times its found 3 matches.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Ok, got it. The title of the question expainls it better than the question itself :)

You need to first know how many times each FK appears:

```
select count(*) as GroupAmount from t1
group by foreign_id
```

Once you have this, you have to group them to get the amount of times each item appears the same way as above. This will result in:

```
select GroupAmount, count(*) GroupAmountTimes from (
  select count(foreign_id) as GroupAmount from t1
  group by foreign_id
) as SubQuery
group by GroupAmount
```

See it in action [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/35661/5)

Answer (score 7):

**Count the number of groups returned by a group by:**

```
select foreign_id as GroupAmount, count(foreign_id) as GroupAmountTimes
from t1
group by foreign_id
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/35661/42