# MySQL - Is it possible to count rows using a regexp?

Tags: mysql

I need help with a MySQL problem. I have two tables, one called `subscription` and another one called `payment`. Every subscription has multiple payments. Some payments are not initiated (`0`), some are failed (`1`) and some are successful (`2`).

Every subscription can generate multiple payment attempts until it gets a successful one. For example:

- First attempt has network connection problems and it gets `status = 0`
- Second attempt reaches the payment API but credit card data is wrong or there are insufficient funds, so it gets `status = 1`
- Third attempt is successful and it gets `status = 2`

The first two can be a more than two, in fact it can look like this:

`0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 2, 0, 2, 1, 2, 2`

So every subscription have multiple payment sequences (monthly or often, not necessary date related), that can be identified by their status with this regex `[0|1]*2`, getting something like:

```
0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2,   // 9
0, 0, 1, 2,                  // 4
1, 0, 1, 2,                  // 4 
2,                           // 1
2,                           // 1
0, 1, 2,                     // 3 
1, 0, 2,                     // 3
0, 2,                        // 2
1, 2,                        // 2 
2                            // 1
```

but, of course, since there are multiple subscriptions, the payment rows are mixed in the database, the only thing that connects them is the `subscription_id`.

What I need to get is the number of subscriptions that had a successful payment from first attempt, second attempt, third, ..., 10th attempt, 10+ attempt.

On the above example it should be:

```
attempts  count
9         1
4         2
3         2
2         2
1         3
```

Is this possible?

**Test data**

```
SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `payment` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`subscription_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`status` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `IDX_6D28840D9A1887DC` (`subscription_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED AUTO_INCREMENT=36 ;

INSERT INTO `payment` (`id`, `subscription_id`, `status`) VALUES
(1, 1, 1),(2, 1, 2),(3, 1, 2),(4, 2, 2),(5, 3, 2),(6, 4, 2),(7, 5, 2),
(8, 6, 1),(9, 6, 2),(10, 7, 2),(11, 7, 2),(12, 8, 0),(13, 8, 1),(14, 8, 2),
(15, 8, 2),(16, 9, 1),(17, 9, 2),(18, 9, 2),(19, 9, 1),(20, 9, 2),(21, 10, 0),
(22, 10, 1),(23, 10, 1),(24, 10, 1),(25, 10, 1),(26, 11, 0),(27, 11, 0),(28, 11, 1),
(29, 11, 1),(30, 11, 1),(31, 8, 0),(32, 8, 1),(33, 8, 2),(34, 10, 1),(35, 10, 2);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `subscription` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`status` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED AUTO_INCREMENT=12 ;

INSERT INTO `subscription` (`id`, `status`) VALUES
(1, 1),(2, 1),(3, 1),(4, 1),(5, 1),(6, 1),(7, 1),
(8, 1),(9, 1),(10, 0),(11, 0);

ALTER TABLE `payment`
ADD CONSTRAINT `sub_id` FOREIGN KEY (`subscription_id`) REFERENCES `subscription` (`id`);
```

**Note:** The test data is not similar to the example above. For the test data the result should look like this:

```
subscription_id    cntAttempts     [attempts counted]
1                  2               1, 2,
1                  1               2, 
2                  1               2, 
3                  1               2, 
4                  1               2, 
5                  1               2, 
6                  2               1, 2, 
7                  1               2, 
7                  1               2, 
8                  3               0, 1, 2, 
8                  1               2, 
9                  2               1, 2, 
9                  1               2, 
9                  2               1, 2, 
10                 7               0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2
11                 5               0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
8                  3               0, 1, 2,
```

For `subscription_id = 10` the last two payments were inserted after `11` and `8` ones at the end.

The expected final result:

```
paymentAttemptsCount    count
1                       9
2                       5
3                       1
4                       0
5                       1
6                       0
7                       1
8                       0
9                       0
10                      0
```

Note: Subscription with `id = 11` has no successful payment.

Comment: Sorry for that! I first wrote the example then I created the test database. I've updated the question with test data expected results. Thanks!

Comment: how do you count the payment sequences per subscription , for example if you have seq1: 0,2 and seq2: 1,2 for a subscription_id = 1, how do you know that you had 2 payments with 2 attempts each and not 2 payments with 3 and 1 attempt respectively. In the db you'll hava 0,1,2,2

Comment: your question may be similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9231447/how-to-count-the-number-of-groups-returned-by-a-group-by

Comment: Your problems arise from your database design. Have a table with all payments (once). A payment is an entity, so have a table for it. Give each of them a number. When you add payment attemps, include that number in your table. And all your problems will go away.

Comment: I'm  not sure that I agree with Solaflare's assessment.

Comment: Well, as far as I understand it, it is what he is trying to do anyway: recreating (and counting) the actual payment structure - one payment is done when a "2" is reached, then a new one is done. And I would assume that a payment entity would consist of more than just the attemps - an amount, a due date, some billing number,  ... that would all not belong in that table. The first expected result will just be a group by that payment number, and the second one is a derivative of that.

Comment: @KatrinnaL if you have 0, 1, 2, 2 with same `subscription_id` then you have a sequence of 3 payments and another one of single successful payment. The referenced question is not what I'm looking for. Thank you!

Comment: @Solarflare the table `payment` has a lot more columns. I used a light schema for testing purposes, the other columns are not important in finding a solution to this problem.

Comment: @Solarflare what might be helpful would be to add an `invoice_number` column in the table, to link those payments, since currently there is none, the invoice number is generated from `payment.id`.

Comment: @Max Damage: What I mean is: you have some entity that has to be paid for by payment attemps. This entity will have an (maybe implicit) number that will group your payment attemps together. That group is what you are looking for. If you have that column - it HAS something to do with "finding a solution to this problem". If not: you might want to add it (otherwise you need to calc it everytime). Imho this number (even as in id) would describe your data. You just missed it when designing/normalizing your datamodel, which now makes an easy task complicated (or at least slow).

Comment: Or to put it in code: if you have your paymentid (lets call it pid), your first query will just be: `select subscription_id, count(*) as cntAttempts, group_concat(status order by id) as attempts_counted from subscriptions group by pid, subscription_id` and the second one: `select cntAttempts, count(*) from (select pid, count(*) as cntAttempts from subscriptions group by pid) a group by cntAttempts`. If you don't have clean data, you have to calculate that pid in a subquery. Some ranking function will do that.

Comment: @Solarflare the entity `subscription` it's not something 'abstract' like a plan, it's more like a product that needs recurrent monthly payments to be available to the owning user. I see your point and, as stated in my previous comment, you are right, I should add another column that links payment sequences, like an invoice number. This will definitely make this data selection way easier. But given the current schema, do you think I can find a solution to get the required result? Thanks for all the input!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned, you actually should add a column for a paymentid/invoicenumber (which will be a foreign key to an invoice table) to group several payment attempts together - since they belong together and your datamodel should represent that logic. Your problem just seems more complicated because you are missing that data.

You can calculate that id on runtime (at least if you added them in order, and did not mix payments for the same `subscription_id`, e.g. because an invoice might be still open the next month and you now try to invoice both). For your first query, you can e.g. use

```
select subscription_id, 
       count(*) as cntAttempts, 
       group_concat(status order by id) as attempts_counted 
from 
  (SELECT id, subscription_id, status, 
         @pid := CASE WHEN @last_status = 2 or subscription_id <> @last_id 
                      THEN @pid + 1 else @pid END as pid,
         @last_id := subscription_id,
         @last_status := status
   from (select @last_id := 0, @pid := 0, @last_status := 0) init, payment
   order by subscription_id, id
  ) as payment_grpd
group by pid, subscription_id;
```

Your second query would need to group this result again, e.g and would look like

```
select cntAttempts, 
       count(*) as count
from 
  (select pid, 
          count(*) as cntAttempts 
   from 
     (SELECT id, subscription_id, status, 
            @pid := CASE WHEN @last_status = 2 or subscription_id <> @last_id 
                         THEN @pid + 1 else @pid END as pid,
            @last_id := subscription_id,
            @last_status := status
      from (select @last_id := 0, @pid := 0, @last_status := 0) init, payment
      order by subscription_id, id
     ) as payment_grpd
     group by pid, subscription_id
  ) as subcounts 
group by cntAttempts;
```

The subquery `payment_grpd` will recalculate your id. If you add the missing relation, your first query would simply look like

```
select subscription_id, 
       count(*) as cntAttempts, 
       group_concat(status order by id) as attempts_counted 
from payment
group by pid, subscription_id;
```

and similarly for the second one. And to normalize, `subscription_id` would probably have to be moved to the reference table.

Comment: Added an `invoice_no` column with `NULL` for sequences with non-successful payment at the end, now selecting the data is easy! Thank you for your support.